# WebForm_PostBackOptions is undefined error in IE10

Tags: asp.net, .net, internet-explorer-10

WebForm_PostBackOptions

is undefined error in IE10 when click button on ASP.NET website

Native:

```
    <asp:Button runat="server" id="btnSearch" 
    OnClientClick="if (!isValid()){return false;};" PostBackUrl="Result.aspx" />
```

Rendered:

```
    <input type="submit" name="BtnSearch" value="SEARCH" id="BtnSearch"
    onclick="if (!isValid()) { return false; };WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;BtnSearch&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, &quot;&quot;, &quot;Result.aspx&quot;, false, false))" >
```

Working in all browser. Kindly help me to close this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: isValid() function code ?

Comment: 'code'function isValid() {if(document.getElementById('txtCityFrom_txtAutoComplete_input').value="") return false; else return true;}

Answer (score 4):

This may be due to the fact that the machine doesn't have latest .Net updates. ASP.Net needs to be updated with latest browser definitions files to recognize new browsers.

The fix is to update the ie.browser and firefox.browser files in \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\\Config\Browsers

There are two ways to fix it: server-wide or site-wide.

Server-wide: install one of the hotfixes from the links below.

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088
  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600100
  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2608565

Site-Wide:

- create App_Browsers folder in your web site root
- copy ie.browser and firefox.browser files into this folder from this zip file:
  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/content/binary/App_BrowsersUpdate.zip

Thanks to Scott Hanselman for the tip: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please check the form tag with runat="server" is there in the aspx file.